# How to make ros communication with dynamixel servo?

Tags: ros, laser, dynamixel, 2dlaserscan, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I converted 3d point cloud data using 2d laser scanner with a servo motor .But now ı want to use dynamixel AX 12A servo motor. How to use this motor with Ros? So how to make ros communication with dynamixel servo? Please help me .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274103/how-to-make-ros-communication-with-dynamixel-servo?/) by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2017-10-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-26**:
Can you update your question to tell us what you've already found yourself? Searching (with Google fi) for `ros dynamixel` returns plenty of results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually, I am also a beginner however currently we are trying a few things related to ROS with Dynamixel. The things you can try are as follows:-

1. Using Dynamixel_SDK which has official support from ROBOTIS  https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/DynamixelSDK
2. Using FTDI driver https://github.com/HumaRobotics/dynamixel_hr   #This link has installation for FTDI
3. dynamixel_motor- This ROS package was used widely till the official SDK came out. However, it still may be useful. https://github.com/arebgun/dynamixel_motor    #This has ROS documentation as well.

Hope this helps.

Note:-

1. The header file called dynamixel.h which we used in MATLAB does not work with Linux. So don't waste your time with that for Linux.
2. We are trying on the EX-106+ model but mostly it should work for your model as well.

---

Originally posted by [aaditya_saraiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/31473/aaditya_saraiya/) with karma: 105 on 2017-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0